# Delete hashs from line but keep string

Tags: c#, hash, url-rewriting, line

I am writing a program that re-writes a text file - initially I just needed to remove any line with a "#" in it, which worked fine - now I need to remove the hashes but keep the string between the hashes. so for example "#####textHere##### i just want the textHere string...

here is my code:

```
            string lineData = "#";
            string copy = "rcpy"; 
            string dash ="-------";
            string total = "total";
            string vv = "vvcp";

            int count = 0;
            string Name = "Name";

            // Read the file and display it line by line.
            using (System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(textBox1.Text))
            {
                using (System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\test4.txt"))
                {
                    //while the reader reads the lines, perform the re-write based on these conditions
                    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        line = line.Trim();

                        if (line.Contains(Name))
                        {
                            count++;
                        }

                        if (line.Contains(Name) && count >= 2 || line.Contains(copy) ||               line.Contains(dash) || line.Contains(total) || line.Contains(vv)) || line.Contains(lineData)) 

                        {
                            //then right to new file
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            string[] keys = new string[] { "R1", "R5" };
                            string result = keys.FirstOrDefault<string>(s=>line.Contains(s));

                            switch(result)
                            {
                                case "R1":
                                    writer.WriteLine("R5" + "\t" + line);
                                    break;
                                case "R5":
                                    writer.WriteLine("R1" + "\t" + line);
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    writer.WriteLine("\t" + line);
                                    break;
                            }
                            //then right to new file
                        }

                    }
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Formatting Complete");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What about this string: `"#####and then suddenly ## what to do?#####"` - do you need to keep the inner `##` or remove that too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use below menioned code

```
if(line.Contains(lineData))
{
 line=line.Replace("#","");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
yourString.Replace("#", String.Empty);
```

Comment: +1, deleted my answer regex not required. `Replace` should be enough.